# How do I create a regular expression to capture {this} text and exclude \{that}?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need a regular expression to capture field names listed in a string. They are listed between 
Here are my requirements:

1. field names in curly braces
2. field names have no spaces
3. curly braces can be escaped with a \

So in the following:

```
capture {this} text and exclude \{that}?
```

The matches are {this} but not {that}.

I'm using PHP and preg_match (i could use a diff function, i'm open to ideas)

Any ideas?
care to explain the result as well for me so I might learn something :)

Comment: Can backslashes themselves be escaped? `capture \\{this}?`

Comment: good point, i would include that too if i knew how :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$s = 'capture {this} text and exclude \{that} {a} \{b} {c}?';
preg_match_all('~(?<!\\\){[^}]+}~', $s, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

In details you can read about negative assertion `(?<!` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookbehind: `(?<!\\)\{[^}]+\}`.  (Remember to escape the `\` for PHP)

The expression `(?<!something)` is a zero-width assertion that will only allow the subsequent expression to match text that isn't preceded by `something`.
Thus, this regex matches `\{[^}]+\}` only if it's not preceded by `\\`.  (The `\` must be escaped)

Comment: 1. you've lost one \ 2. you've lost quantifier for ^}

Comment: @zerkms: 1. Huh? I'm not showing a PHP string. 2. Fixed; thanks.